# Finding the parent object of a callback function

Tags: javascript, oop, callback, this

I have a function:

```
myObject.myFunction = function(callback){
  callback();
}
```

and a callback

```
randomObject.callBack = function(){
  console.log(this);
}
```

if I call `randomObject.callBack()` directly, I get the parent object in the console. However, if I call `myObject.myFunction(randomObject.callBack)`, it logs a DOM Element.

How can I access the parent object?

---

**Note**

I do not know the name of the callbacks parent object ahead of runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context (i.e. `this` value) of an object is determined at the time the function is run, *not* at the time it is defined.  Passing `randomObject.callBack` to another function does not send the context (the `randomObject` bit); it just sends the function.

Presumably the context is set when `myFunction` calls it. Since you aren't explicitly providing a context (e.g. with `call` or `apply`), the context will be the `window` object.

You can change this by explicitly saying what the context of the function should be before it is run. You can do this with the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
myObject.myFunction(randomObject.callBack.bind(randomObject))
```

Now when you call `callback` inside `myFunction`, `randomObject` will be logged.

Note that `bind` is relatively new; not all browsers support it. The MDN page I linked to above has a bit of code that will make it work in all browsers.

Comment: what if I don't know the name of randomObject at time of writing, I need to establish it at run time?

Comment: So the code is flexible, it doesn't need rewriting because a I created a new instance of the object.

Comment: Ignore that, misinterpreted (read: scanned) your answer. Works a charm. Ta muchly!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you invoke a function without an object, inside the function  `this` will point to Window object.To avoid this we usually do like this

```
myObject.myFunction = function(callback){
  callback();
}


randomObject.callBack = function(){
  console.log(this);
}

function proxyCallback(){
     randomObject.callBack();
}

myObject.myFunction(proxyCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, `this` refers to the object context in which a function is *called*.  This is not necessarily related to any object on which it has been *defined*.

You can think of it as though functions are not defined as members of objects, but called as members of objects.

There are four things that `this` might resolve to, depending on context.

1. A newly created object, if the function call was preceded by the new keyword.
2. The Object to the left of the dot when the function was called.
3. The Global Object (typically window), if neither of the above are provided.
4. The first argument provided to a `call` or `apply` function.

In your situation, something like this might be appropriate:

```
myObject.myFunction(function(){randomObject.callBack()});
```

This creates a closure so that within `myFunction`, `callback` is called as a member of `randomObject`.

Comment: You forgot about how `.bind` overwrites all the rules

Comment: @Raynos IIRC, `.bind` is just a function that creates a closure of the type in my example.  Depending on how it's implemented, it would conform to my rules 2 or 4.  Am I wrong?

Comment: `var o = {}; o.foo = f.bind(null); o.foo(); // this === null`. `.bind` is hard bound. `f.bind(null).call({}); // this === null`. You can't undo that binding.

Comment: How does that differ from `o2.foo = function(){f.apply(null)}; o2.foo()` and `(function(){f.apply(null)}).call({});`?  You can't undo that binding either.

Comment: I would say the opposite - `.bind` emulates that mechanism of creating closures.

Comment: bind and closures don't have anything to do which each other

Comment: Even John Resig says that ECMAScript 5 bind is virtually identical to Prototype bind, which creates a closure in much the same way I have demonstrated.

Comment: Using a closure is a particular method of emulating bind. Whether a particular javascript engine uses closures in it's implementation of bind is implementation specific.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6622/discussion-between-paul-butcher-and-raynos)